# Angular 2: Remove CSS from a dynamically created component when destroyed

Tags: angular, dynamic, components

How do I remove all CSS classes that were added to the DOM when I destroy a dynamically created component.

Create Component (which add the component's CSS classes to the DOM):

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component)
const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector)
```

Destroy component

```
componentRef.destory()
// I need the CSS Classes which were added to the DOM to be destroyed as well
```

I cannot manually remove them because I will have no Idea what the CSS classes are; therefore, I need to remove all CSS classes tied the creation of that component.